# Insulating pad for inflatable hot tub

Tags: insulation, hot-tub

I got an inflatable hot tub which I want to place on an existing concrete surface.

However, I am concerned about heat loss since concrete is a fairly good thermal conductor. I would like to insulate it as best as possible.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I was thinking of getting rigid foam board insulation such as [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Owens-Corning-FOAMULAR-NGX-F-250-2-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-SSE-R-10-XPS-Rigid-Foam-Board-Insulation-52DDNGX/315197962). I could get 1 or two boards and cut a circular pad, nicely matching the shake of the hot tub. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only energy loss but the concrete will damage the bottom of the tub.

Use interlocking exercise floor mats.  Lightweight foam ones are cheap and sufficient for this job.